# jQuery - scroll to top with an offset

Tags: jquery

The function

```
var navigationFn = {
goToSection: function(id,offset) {
    if ($(offset)=="") {var offset = -10;}
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(id).offset().top + offset
    }, 1500);
  }
}
```

should move the user to an id with a special offset. If there is no specified offset, it should be `-10` as default.

This works fine for me.

```
navigationFn.goToSection('#id',-70);
```

But I have several "old" calls like

```
navigationFn.goToSection('#id');
```

They bring me to the top of the html document, not to the id.

Is it possible to use both calls without changing the old ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`offset` is not a jQuery Object but instead it is a number type function argument so you do not need `$(offset)` or something.

Just do `offset = offset || -10;`

This will set offset to -10 if not passed in the function

```
var navigationFn = {
goToSection: function(id,offset) {
    var offset = offset || -10;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(id).offset().top + offset
    }, 1500);
  }
}
```